# Google Analytics Funnel reports differ from pageviews

Tags: google-analytics

I've created goal funnels with a required first step, /cancel. When I look at my pageviews reports, the unique pageviews for the /cancel page differ from the value reported in the funnel visualization for the required step 1. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the funnel report the number is **sessions** and *not pageviews*.

Here are the definitions:

**Sessions**: total number of Sessions within the date range. A session is the period time a user is actively engaged with your website, app, etc. All usage data (Screen Views, Events, Ecommerce, etc.) is associated with a session.

**Pageviews**: is the total number of pages viewed. Repeated views of a single page are counted.

**Unique Pageviews**: is the number of sessions during which the specified page was viewed at least once. A unique pageview is counted for each page URL + page Title combination.

It is important to know that the unique page metric does not closely match the deduplication of the number of times a page has been viewed in a session, as a **unique pageview** in Analytics *is counted for each page URL + page Title combination*.

So you can't consider page views because goals talk about sessions and you can't compare these metrics because they are different information with different scope.

Comment: Thanks! I understand they're not pageviews, but the numbers for sessions to the first step of the funnel, and the *unique pageviews* for that page should be similar, or the same, right? Since a unique pageview is # sessions for that page? The numbers are off by an average of 5, so they're pretty close. But why are they not equal?

Comment: A reason is written in the answer: unique pageview in Analytics is counted for each page URL + page Title combination